# take coordinates from the database and create markers

Tags: android, sqlite, coordinates, google-maps-markers, android-maps

Goodmorning everyone! My target is to take a set of coordinates from my SQLite database and insert them as a marker in the map.
I tried to collect the data through double but nothing; then I tried to take the coordinates in this way:

```
public LatLng getLatLngMetod()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=helper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor crs=db.query("tab", null, null, null, null, null, null);

    LatLng locati = null;

    while(crs.moveToNext())
    {
        String cord = crs.getString(crs.getColumnIndex("coordinate"));

        String[] latlong =  cord.split(",");
        double latitude = Double.parseDouble(latlong[0]);
        double longitude = Double.parseDouble(latlong[1]);
        locati = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    }
    return locati;
}
```

I then tried to call the method this way:

```
mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(dbManager.latLngMetod()));
```

I saved the file in the database as well:

```
            coordinateList = latLng.latitude + ", " + latLng.longitude;
            dbManager = new DbManager(getActivity());
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put("coordinate", coordinateList);
            dbManager.setProvider(contentValues);
```

The error log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.mattia.provaconfragment, PID: 31147
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.location.Location com.example.mattia.provaconfragment.OnDataUpdate.getPosition()' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.mattia.provaconfragment.PrimoFragment$override.updateMap(PrimoFragment.java:253)
                  at com.example.mattia.provaconfragment.PrimoFragment$override.access$dispatch(PrimoFragment.java)
                  at com.example.mattia.provaconfragment.PrimoFragment.updateMap(PrimoFragment.java:0)
                  at com.example.mattia.provaconfragment.MainActivity.onConnected(MainActivity.java:138)
                  at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzm.zzq(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaat.zzo(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaar.zzwi(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaar.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaav.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaag.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzl$1.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf$zzj.zzxG(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf$zza.zzb(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf$zza.zzu(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf$zze.zzxH(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf$zzd.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5610)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
```

Comment: What exactly is the Question? What kind of help do you need?

Comment: the problem is that me error code and do not understand why

Comment: Where's the error? Can you post the Log?

Comment: done! but I do not understand how the object is null

Comment: I state that I am working with fragment

Comment: @MattDeveloper Log the values returned by the function. You'll find the culprit.

Comment: ok thanks could fit through @PradumnKumarMahanta